# Cloning a MySQL database on the same MySql instance in Window 10

Tags: mysql

I go through so many solution of it but none of them is working in window 10 previously I was working on window 7 but after move on window 10 this mysql query is not working on window 10 command line.

> c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin\mysql.exe -uroot -ppassword
>   test_db1 | mysql.exe -u root -ppassword test_db2;
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin\mysql.exe -uroot -ppassword ifinance_hea' at line 1

I have given full path of mysql.exe

Note:- I know There are many solutions are available but none of them working for me.

I also tried this:-

> mysqldump -uroot -ppassword test_db1 | mysql -u root -ppassword test_db2;
>    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -uroot -ppassword ifinance_hea | mysql -u root -ppassword ifinance_hea' at line 1

My code is:-

```
public void copyDB(BRANCH branch, Date processDate, String newDbName) throws IOException {
        Session session = getSessionFactory(branch).openSession();
        try {
            String sqlC = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + newDbName;

            Query queryC = session.createSQLQuery(sqlC);
            queryC.executeUpdate();
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(Util.getProcessBuilder());

            Process p = builder.start();
            // get stdin of shell
            BufferedWriter p_stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
            p_stdin.write(c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin\mysql.exe -uroot -ppassword test_db1 | mysql.exe -u root -ppassword test_db2);


            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();

            // finally close the shell by execution exit command
            p_stdin.write("exit");
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();

            Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(s.nextLine());
            }
            s.close();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your questions to include the commands you have tried and the results and/or error messages you get when executing them.

Comment: Where are you trying to run these commands? It looks like you are not running them in the command line, but instead tries to run them inside a MySQL client like php's `mysqli_query()` function. These are not SQL statements, these are command to be executed in a shell.

Comment: I am running these commands on command line

Comment: It doesn't look like that. "You have an error in your SQL syntax [...]" is an error you get from MySQL, not from the command line. And having command stuff like "[...] \bin\mysql.exe -uroot -ppassword [...]" inside the error message of the MySQL error indicates that you are trying to run a shell command as a SQL query. That doesn't work. Please verify that you run your commands you want to run in a shell and NOT inside a MySQL client. If you can't verify that, please edit your question to include the screenshot of your command line/shell and how you try to execute the commands.

Comment: Now i have update complete code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your source code, which can be compiled and tested by others. Methods like `Util.getProcessBuilder()` aren't visible in your given source code.